# MacBook Pro com.apple.BezelServices suspicious

Tags: macbook-pro

I am checking device logs of MacBook Pro.
I have noticed a process repeatedly.

It has time, process name and some messages.

I see 'loginwindow(BezelServices)'
In category it says 'loginwindow'
Some thread id
Then in message
"Sending keyboard PWM value 114"
Some time same message with different code 110 etc.

Could someone explain me what is going on?

Comment: Can you add the relevant log lines by copy/pasting them into the question as text?

Comment: What's suspicious about it? BezelServices handles HID comms, so seeing keyboard values is not in itself suspicious.

Comment: Can somebody confirm if it is normal to see such lines in system logs or do my machine suffer from any keylogger? Sending keyboard PWM value 114